# Removing a page from google index

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, noindex

I've been having a problem with redirecting a page on my website from google index via htaccess files. I've been using

Redirect 301 http://example.com/?attachment_id=99 http://example.com

but it doesn't do anything..

anyone know of a better way to fix this problem?

my goal is to get it from index on google.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mod_rewrite to match against query strings .

Try this in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^attachment_id=99$  
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.com? [NC,L,R]
```

Empty question mark at the end of the target url is important ,as it discards the orignal query strings.